# Hibernate + Derby. Database not found

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I'm created `DBUSER` database with `USERS` table. But when I'n trying to connect to the database I take `SQLException`. Also I can connect to database using `ij`.

## **Log:**

```
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:06 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version 
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:07 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.source
forge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/petrez/user/DBUser.hbm.xml
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:07 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.source
forge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:07 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImplconfigure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:10 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImplconfigure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:10 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverMa
nagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:10 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] at URL [jdbc:derby:DBUSER]
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:10 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=admin, password=****}
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Database 'DBUSER' not found.
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:10 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect 
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder use
ContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:11 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
 
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 40000, SQLState: XJ004
Jun 22, 2013 6:36:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Database 'DBUSER' not found.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
        at com.petrez.App.main(App.java:16)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'DBUSER' not found.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'DBUSER' not found.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 20 more
```

## **DBUser.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.petrez.user.DBUser" table="USERS">
        <id name="userId" type="int">
            <column name="USER_ID" precision="5" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="USERNAME" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdBy" type="string">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate" type="date">
            <column name="CREATED_DATE" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

## **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:DBUSER</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/petrez/user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Mistake was found. In dependecies I writed `derby` not `derbyclient`. Thanks for your time. It's really stupid mistake. Also I'm new in Hibernate and JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [create = true](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernatecfgxml-settings-derby) with url string.

```
<property name=”hibernate.connection.url”>jdbc:derby:DBUSER;create=true</property>
```

It [creates](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefattrib26867.html) the standard database specified within the database connection URL Derby system and then connects to it. If the database cannot be created, the error appears in the error log and the connection attempt fails with an SQLException indicating that the database cannot be found.

If the database already exists, creates a connection to the existing database and an SQLWarning is issued.

Comment: I tryed this. With `create=true` I take `java.sql.SQLException: Schema 'USERS' does not exist`. Also I don't know what is this property and what I need to write for this property. I tryed delete this property, set him as `admin`, `DBUSER` and `USERS` (as my table in db `DBUSER`)

Comment: [http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernatecfgxml-settings-derby](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernatecfgxml-settings-derby) hope this link help you. try copying configuration for apache derby from page and change the required properties as per your need. then try running your project if it fails then try it with changing the database name in configuration